# Secure post variables with loop to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, security

I am trying to make my php scripts more secure.

Because i got a form with alot of post variables I don't want to check each variable.

On stackoverflow i found this script at a post but it had a score of -2 so i think this isn't secure  but i cant find any reason why it woudln't be secure

```
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
     $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
     $_POST[$key] = $value ;
 }
```

Is this script secure to make the `$_POST` variables safe ?

edit Safe to use in a sql statement

Comment: Define security. Are you looking for XSS prevention? Do you want protection from SQL injection? Or do you wish to secure the data from tampering/snooping while being passed to your server?

Comment: safe to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit overdone, but should keep you safe.

However, to simplify things, you should consider using *prepared statements*. Strongly suggested.

See this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Also, meet my buddy Bobby: http://bobby-tables.com/

Those should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great, but... No one solution fits all problems and you haven't really stated any problem to solve. here are some pointers that may help you.

[`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is **deprecated**, plus it doesn't make your variable safe to use in php code, just to copy/paste in a sql statement string. Also it's used without a connection, so character set cannot be taken into account (unless there happens to be a global connection, which is another bad idea)

Personally, I consider changing values in `$_POST` to be a bad practice because now you don't know what your user **actually posted**.

However; If you take out the `mysql_real_escape_string` (only do that sort of thing when you're working with a database in the next statement) and write the changed values to another array and read from that in your code (i.e. not `$_POST`) it could be quite usable for your situation.